# Anything Slider and WordPress extra black slide after each "real" slide

Tags: php, wordpress, slider

i'm using the latest version of anything slider on wp 3.0.4 and i'm having a problem. The slider works but for each slides it adds an extra empty slide -.- (if i have 2 slides it adds 1 slide per "real" slide)

This is the code that i use in my page on wordpress

http://pastie.org/1492604

how do i fix this stupid problem ? Thanks

edit: this is the generated code from wordpress i think that there is nothing wrong

http://pastie.org/1492679

Also from my custom post type there no blank posts.

Comment: it seems your loop iterating twice once for real post and again with blank posts. you can put a condition to check id is not blank before rendering image

Comment: Could you also paste the output generated?

Comment: i've added the link to the generated output into the open post

Answer (score 1):

just don't hit return before entering the next image, wordpress enters a break automatically which messes with the script.

instead of

```
<div id="slider>
   <img src="..." /> 
   <img src="..." /> 
</div>
```

use

```
<div id="slider>
   <img src="..." /><img src="..." />
</div>
```